# How do you create a string from variables?

Tags: r, string

In R, I want to create a string using stored values.  In Python I would use [f-strings](https://realpython.com/python-f-strings/) for improved readability.

```
>>> a_val = 1
>>> b_val = 99

>>> fname_python = f'a{a_val}_b{b_val}.csv'
>>> fname_python
a1_b99.csv
```

I have found 2 ways to do this in R, (1) `paste` and (2) `sprintf`.

```
a_val <- 1
b_val <- 99

# paste and collapse are best when you have an existing vector
# fname1 <- paste(c('a', a_val, '_b', b_val, '.csv'), collapse = '')  
# paste0 is better in this example
fname1 <- paste0('a', a_val, '_b', b_val, '.csv')
# 'a1_b99.csv'

fname2 <- sprintf('a%d_b%d.csv', a_val, b_val)
# 'a1_b99.csv'
```

Is there something more similar to Python's f-strings?

Comment: If i do not need a specific separator, I always use `paste0`

Comment: It's style. I prefer `sprintf` for "fill-in-the-blank" style strings, where there are holes to fill in in a string. `paste` is good when most all the pieces of the string are already in vectors and you don't want to keep alternating between constants and variables. The example in your question is a good example of where I prefer `sprintf` - I think it's more concise and more readable.

Comment: If you don't concatenate, you will not have to collapse. In other words you can just do `paste0('a', a_val, '_b', b_val, '.csv')`. Note that I use `paste0` which has '' as a default delimiter (whereas `paste` default del. is the space)

Comment: preface any function with fn$ from gsubfn and then you can use `$var` or ` `R code` ` to perform string interpoloation on arguments.  e.g. `library(gsubfn); fn$read.csv("a\`a_val\`_b\`b_val\`.csv") `   If you use the $var form rather than the backquote form you can't have underscore in the variable name since special characters terminate it.  e.g. `a <- b <- 3; fname <- fn$identity("a$a_b$b.csv"); read.csv(fname)`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

An option is the `glue` library by Jim Hester from Wickham's [tidyverse](https://www.tidyverse.org/).

Example from [the Github README](https://github.com/tidyverse/glue#long-strings-are-broken-by-line-and-concatenated-together):

```
library(glue)

name        <- "Fred"
age         <- 50
anniversary <- as.Date("1991-10-12")
glue('My name is {name},',
  ' my age next year is {age + 1},',
  ' my anniversary is {format(anniversary, "%A, %B %d, %Y")}.')
```

> ```
> My name is Fred, my age next year is 51, my anniversary is Saturday,
> October 12, 1991.
> ```

Comment: I stand corrected. My brain just defaults tidyverse to Wickham.

Comment: Jim Hester's [github bio](https://github.com/jimhester) says "Working with @hadley to make data science in R easier, faster and more fun."